# Is PhantomJS supported on Sun solaris and AIX?

Tags: phantomjs

Is PhantomJS supprted on *Sun solaris* and *IBM-AIX*.

I can see some threads on github regarding this feature request and no support for 64 bit Sun solaris: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10521

Is PhantomJS fully supported on *Sun solaris* and *IBM-AIX*.
If no? When can we expect to have PhantomJS for *Sun solaris* and *IBM-AIX*.

In particular I am concerned about the support on following Operating systems.

- Windows Server 2008  R2
- Solaris Sparc 10
- Redhat Enterprise Server 4.x
- SuSE Linux
- IBM AIX 6.1
- SuSE Linux